# Underline text links but not buttons and images

Tags: css

I added tcode underneath to underline links and hover effect is adjusted in theme. Since I have links in buttons and images now they are all underline. I need to keep underline for text links only. Please help

article a { text-decoration: none; border-bottom:2px solid #00D07D;}

Comment: _links in buttons_? what do you mean? Please provide more detail to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

```css
article a:not(.except){
text-decoration: none; border-bottom:2px solid #00D07D;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <a>Link1</a>
  <a>Link12</a>
  <a class="except">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/search?q=flower&sxsrf=AOaemvIv5piN4OwOjyDB0mr1JFWYStW9oQ:1643109380107&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&vet=1&fir=_L-zJjp2lefhCM%252CsMmBYcrjWuigoM%252C_%253BkynP2p55eMS7TM%252CMqJ0o7Xjxwc15M%252C_%253BRfUQ_0SdSVxZyM%252CV4JMFD_QVN1xmM%252C_%253BrwqXxYAWHAml0M%252CKHb_DrQoiHHqIM%252C_%253BV0PEfdCjSWAL_M%252CTE6or1FVU4DnNM%252C_%253BiVQQ4BLVOiawRM%252C-JSzIkf42ZvU1M%252C_%253BFq2ReKTzIsMA5M%252CLo6lwABxk0AZfM%252C_%253B18zFKrn_p7MNqM%252Cl77oSW3HC1cYZM%252C_%253Bq8XvrYfBOPD6WM%252CW50-Xx0zumPDkM%252C_%253BsAeD2IMVh242pM%252C94jcBxR-2b3nTM%252C_%253BGe0sPl2wtwPeYM%252C6ZeVwdp2vU8abM%252C_%253Bad_EARqn8HNGCM%252CKut2T3IeAU8u9M%252C_%253BIeXj87CM0RmigM%252C3ggE4sC2ipmRxM%252C_%253BX_BrNWU_72e_nM%252C6QnaOLvEQovLfM%252C_%253BEX5OjZ4wVKWUZM%252CNF4Pp3x2g6jFJM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kTfScOSl7Syuc6ZvSEBcI6ApYpm8Q&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC6LW348z1AhVigv0HHYnBDOQQ9QF6BAgDEAE#imgrc=_L-zJjp2lefhCM"/>
  </a>
</article>
```